# Do you continue to gain love when the app is closed?

Tags: 10-billion-wives

In the game [10 Billion Wives](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/10-billion-wives/id969657566), do you continue to gain love when the app is closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, but at a drastically reduced rate.**

The game's description on the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/10-billion-wives/id969657566) says the following about LPS (Love Per Second):

> Q. Why is the background LPS the way it is?
>
> A. This is in order to keep the game balanced. While the app is
> closed, the LPS rate goes down to 0.04. This will continue for 9 hours
> after closing the app.